# Json response via HTTPRequest differ then on website

Tags: python-3.x, azure, http, data-science, face-recognition

I'm using Microsoft Azure to detect Faces attributes.
I uploaded the first image from this page:
https://photographylife.com/nikon-24mm-f1-4-image-samples.

When I put it on the API website () I get the complete Json (with faceId, faceRectangle , faceAttributes), however using HTTP request the Json is partial (no faceAttributes).

```
headers  = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key, "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream" }
response = requests.post(face_api_url, headers=headers, data=image_data)
response.raise_for_status()
json_analysis = response.json()   
print(json_analysis)
```

Here, json_analysis has no field FaceAttributes:

```
[{'faceId': '9bcf9353-1880-4a46-be00-58a992d8e7f8', 'faceRectangle': {'top': 47, 'left': 99, 'width': 65, 'height': 65}}]
```

What might be the reason?

Comment: Could you post full request URL?

Comment: @ThuanNg face_api_url = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without special query parameter, the return only contains `faceId` and `faceRectangle`. You need to set `returnFaceAttributes` to return the designated attributes

`https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceAttributes={attribute}`

Attribute is string type and can be separated with comma, e.g. `returnFaceAttributes=age,hair`. There is **no option in the URL query string** to select All attributes.

`https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,hair`

Sample full request is as follows:

```
POST https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,hair HTTP/1.1
Host: westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••

{
    "url":"https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/20100419-Nikon-24mm-Test-242-960x638.jpg"
}
```

..and response

```
[{
  "faceId": "68629eb6-f483-4c1c-b74f-078ad521c2d7",
  "faceRectangle": {
    "top": 257,
    "left": 349,
    "width": 183,
    "height": 183
  },
  "faceAttributes": {
    "age": 6.0,
    "hair": {
      "bald": 0.01,
      "invisible": false,
      "hairColor": [{
        "color": "brown",
        "confidence": 0.99
      }, {
        "color": "black",
        "confidence": 0.94
      }, {
        "color": "other",
        "confidence": 0.19
      }, {
        "color": "red",
        "confidence": 0.17
      }, {
        "color": "blond",
        "confidence": 0.13
      }, {
        "color": "gray",
        "confidence": 0.06
      }]
    }
  }
}]
```

You need to make sure the host you call (westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com) must use the API key of the Face API resource in the same location. In your case, since you call to the host in West Central US, your Face API resource must be deployed in this location. Otherwise you will receive 401.

[image]

Comment: You must check your location. Make sure the given key of your Face API resource and the host must be the same.

Comment: for the first URL there was no permission problem.. what do you mean by "key of your Face API resource and the host must be the same"? What host?

Comment: This is the host westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com . I just edited my answer to give more details.

Comment: Yeah the problem was the host, Thanks!